# install Haskell through GHC in fish

Tags: xcode, bash, haskell, ghc, fish

I'd like to install Haskell using [GHC](https://ghcformacosx.github.io/), recommended.

I did instructions that said but it warns me:
[image: GHC]

1. 1st warn:

   > !These instructions were written for users who use bash or zsh, not `/usr/local/bin/fish`.
   >   Hopefully you know what you're doing!

Using fish, unfortunately, I edit the instructions in fish version:

```
$ cat ~/.config/fish/config.fish
...
set GHC_DOT_APP /Applications/ghc-7.10.3.app
if test -d $GHC_DOT_APP
    set PATH $HOME/.local/bin $HOME/.cabal/bin $GHC_DOT_APP/Contents/bin $PATH
end
...
$ echo $PATH
/Users/hongbook/.local/bin /Users/hongbook/.cabal/bin /Applications/ghc-7.10.3.app/Contents/bin /Users/hongbook/.fzf/bin /Users/hongbook/.rvm/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /opt/X11/bin /usr/local/go/bin /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin /Users/hongbook/.rvm/bin
```

Also, wrote that, above instructions too in `~/.profile`.

2. 2nd warn:

   > Xcode is not installed

But I've already got it.

```
$ xcode-select --version 
xcode-select version 2349.
```

Refresh checklist doesn't work.

Comment: I would recommend you to get started like this: https://haskell-lang.org/get-started/osx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by other installation ways:

1. Follow the instructions of:
   https://haskell-lang.org/get-started/osx

or

2. Download it(it takes long time..):
   https://www.haskell.org/platform/